# Cassandra start error - Exception encountered during startup: The seed provider lists no seeds

Tags: windows, cassandra, datastax

I am thus far unable to successfully run cassandra.  I have arrived at a point in my efforts where I believe it is more efficient to reach out for help.

Installation method: `datastax-ddc-64bit-3.9.0.msi`

**OS: Windows 7**

**Symptoms:**

```
cmd> net start DataStax-DDC-Server
```

**results in cmd output 'service is starting' and 'service was started successfully'.**

datastax_ddc_server-stdout.log has this subsequent output, that is likely relevant:

```
WARN  10:38:17 Seed provider couldn't lookup host *myIPaddress*
```

Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: The seed provider lists no seeds.

```
ERROR 10:38:17 Exception encountered during startup: The seed provider lists no seeds.
```

$

```
cmd> nodetool status
```

***results in the following error message:***

```
Error: Failed to connect to ‘127.0.0.1:7199’: Connection refused
```

I would also like to note that the Cassandra CQL Shell closes immediately after I open it.. I think that it quickly flashes an error similar to above.

Please be patient with me if I have included some useless information or am not approaching my issue from the correct perspective. I have not worked with apache cassandra before, nor have I configured a machine to facilitate an installation of any database engine.

Any help/insight is much appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Do the IP addresses you specified for the seed provider and the listen_address match? In a single-node cluster scenario you have(?) to set the single node to be its own seed node.

Comment: This was my problem.. I made a typo the specifying seed provider in cassandra.yaml.  Thank you for this insight, I would not have recognized my mistake.   Is there a way to mark that you have solved this issue?